# Laravel Testing Error

Tags: testing, laravel, controller, tdd

I just started with learning how to test within Laravel. I came across some problems though..
I'm testing my controller and want to check if a View has a variable assigned.

My controller code:

```
class PagesController extends \BaseController {

   protected $post;

   public function __construct(Post $post) {
      $this->post = $post;
   }

   public function index() {
      $posts = $this->post->all();
      return View::make('hello', ['posts' => $posts]);
   }
}
```

And my view contains a foreach loop to display all posts:

```
@foreach ($posts as $post)
   {{post->id}}
@endforeach
```

Last but not least my test file:

```
class PostControllerTest extends TestCase {

public function __construct()
{
    // We have no interest in testing Eloquent
    $this->mock = Mockery::mock('Eloquent', 'Post');
}

public function tearDown()
{
    Mockery::close();
}

public function testIndex() {

    $this->mock->shouldReceive('all')->once()->andReturn('foo');
    $this->app->instance('Post', $this->mock);
    $this->call('GET', '/');
    $this->assertViewHas('posts');

}

}
```

Now comes the problem, when I run "phpunit" the following error appears:

ErrorException: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Any ideas why phpunit returns this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
$this->mock->shouldReceive('all')->once()->andReturn('foo');
```

`$this->post->all()` (which is what you're mocking) should return an array, and that's what your view expects.  You're returning a string.

```
$this->mock->shouldReceive('all')->once()->andReturn(array('foo'));
```

should take care of the error you have, though you'll then get an error of the "Getting property of non-object" type.

You could do this:

```
$mockPost = new stdClass();
$mockPost->id = 1;
$this->mock->shouldReceive('all')->once()->andReturn(array($mockpost));
```

Comment: Thanks! This works, but only when I add {{posts}} it gives the error: Array to string conversion. Is there a way to solve this too?

Comment: I used FactoryMuff for creating a quick post like so:       
$mockPost = FactoryMuff::create('Post');
Yet this doesn't solve the problem when I'm calling {{$posts}} but it does populate all the other fields of Post (such as body).

Comment: You can't just echo {{posts}} because it's an array -- you need to loop over it and echo individual entries, as in the code in your question.

Comment: Ah I'm sorry.. laravel converts arrays to json when you do {{$posts}} and thats not done in my test. Thanks anyways, my bad there ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should mock the view as well:

```
public function testIndex() {
    $this->mock->shouldReceive('all')->once()->andReturn('foo');
    $this->app->instance('Post', $this->mock);
    View::shouldReceive('make')->with('hello', array('posts', 'foo'))->once();
    $this->call('GET', '/');
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It returns the following error:ErrorException: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: I fixed it up. Ignore the original answer, just do this

Comment: did you switch the mock of your model back to what you originally had in your code? i.e. it should be back to `$this->mock->shouldReceive('all')->once()->andReturn('foo');` - not the array anymore...?

Comment: This doesnt work either. Error:
Mockery\Exception\NoMatchingExpectationException: No matching handler found for Mockery_1_Illuminate_View_Factory::make("hello", array('posts'=>'foo',)). Either the method was unexpected or its arguments matched no expected argument list for this method

Comment: yes I did exactly as you said in your updated answer. The test succeeds if I replace @foreach etc. with {{posts}}, with my code. It has to do something with the foreach or something.